# call a MATLAB function in GAMS

Tags: matlab, gams-math

Is it possible  to use a function
 of MATLAB  in GAMS code. 
I have a matrix in my GAMS cod , and  I need to have inverse and determinant of matrix ,  is it possible to call a Determinant function  of Matlab in GAMS ?  If it's possible How?

Comment: This could be helpful for you: http://support.gams.com/matlab_and_gams:interfacing_optimization_and_visualization_software_via_the_gdxmrw_utilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling GAMS with MATLAB is made possible with the data exchange tools between GAMS and MATLAB called GDXMRW. You can learn more about the process of Data Transfer from the link below.
https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/T_GDXMRW.html